# Worklight - Environment specific CSS

Tags: css, user-interface, input, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm developing a hybrid app for couple of platforms:

- android
- windows8

I'm using jQuery Mobile as a javascript framework. On Windows8 tablet there is a problem with input fields of type text and password which have their own borders. I traced the problem down to the order in which css stylesheets are loaded. On windows8 platform Worklight studio always adds few lines in between the bottom of the css load list and script tags:

```
<link href="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0/css/ui-light.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0/js/base.js"></script>
<script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0/js/ui.js"></script>
```

In "ui-light.css" there are few CSS attributes which override "border: none" on inputs (by default if one uses jquery mobile css).

Now the question:
Is there a way in worklight to customize the order of load for css specific to the environment (android, windows, etc.)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no. These file references are injected by the Worklight builder during build-time as it  generats the HTML file, and this is a process which you cannot alter.

What you should consider doing, though, is override the "problematic" CSS rules in your own CSS by adding `!important`.

```
border: 1px solid black !important;
```